# How to convert a keynote to something that I can run on Windows, with the least loss of quality?

Tags: windows, microsoft-powerpoint, file-conversion, iwork-keynote

I am going to do a presentation on a Windows computer. However, I don't have Powerpoint installed on my Mac. My Windows PC doesn't have PowerPoint either :( It only has the OpenOffice.org thingy.

Because I think Keynote is easier to use than OpenOffice, I eventually ended up creating a Keynote. Now I need to convert this Keynote to something that can be used to do the presentation properly (not limited to PowerPoint).

In the "File -> Export to" menu, I see that I can convert it to PowerPoint and HTML for this purpose. So I tried both, here are the results:

PowerPoint:

- Some animations are replaced with similar animations
- The "Blink" Action animation becomes very slow
- The transition between slides is replaced with a similar transition
- The font is not supported
- Links function correctly

HTML:

- Some animations are replaced with similar animations but less similar than the PowerPoint one
- "Blink" animations function correctly
- The transition functions correctly
- The font is supported
- Links have no effect (Nothing happens on click)

Also, note that the HTML version is the result of opening `index.html` in Internet Explorer. I tried with Chrome and Firefox but it shows nothing if I used them. This is *weird*.

Can anybody suggest how to convert a Keynote to a Windows-compatible version with most of the things functioning the same?

P.S. I don't want to convert it to Quick Time because I still want to be able to click to go to the next slide.

Comment: Conversions between different presentation programs and from presentation programs to HTML have always been compromises, at best. Effects and features you use in one problem may not be present in another program, so an approximation is the best you can hope for.  You might be better off installing the same version of the OpenOffice.org thingy on both your Mac and on the target PC.

Comment: Maybe try the [PowerPoint Viewer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13) on your Windows machine. Maybe it will present the exported to ppt(x) correctly

Comment: as @Zina said, just convert it to Powerpoint and use the viewer from Microsoft. It's distributed freely to run .pptx presentations